Data-defined override width of line vector layer using PyQGIS
I am trying to set the width of a line vector layer using the data-defined override option. I want to set the option using PyQGIS in QGIS 3.38.3.
Here is my code, but I just get: <QgsProperty: invalid>
What is wrong here?
# Access the project and the layer
layers = project.mapLayersByName("lines")

# Ensure the layer is valid
if layers:
    layer = layers[0]
    
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    
    property_collection = QgsPropertyCollection()
    scale = """coalesce(scale_exp("id", 0, 3, 1, 10, 0.57), 0)"""
    property_collection.setProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyWidth,QgsProperty.fromExpression(scale))
    symbol.setDataDefinedProperties(property_collection)
    print(property_collection.property(0))

    # Apply the symbol to the layer
    layer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol))
    layer.triggerRepaint()

    print("Line width set based on 'id' attribute.")
else:
    print("Layer not found.")


You should use QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeWidth instead of QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyWidth.
Next, you should set the data defined properties to the symbol layer not the symbol itself.
Finally, your print statement returns <QgsProperty: invalid> because you are passing the wrong enum key (StrokeWidth is 5; Width is 9). However you are better off accessing it the same way you set it e.g.
print(property_collection.property(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeWidth))

So:
layers = project.mapLayersByName("lines")

if layers:
    layer = layers[0]
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    property_collection = QgsPropertyCollection()
    scale = """coalesce(scale_exp("id", 0, 3, 1, 10, 0.57), 0)"""
    property_collection.setProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeWidth, QgsProperty.fromExpression(scale))
    symbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperties(property_collection)
    print(property_collection.property(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeWidth))
    layer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol))
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    print("Line width set based on 'id' attribute.")
else:
    print("Layer not found.")

Alternatively, if you want to work directly with the symbol, you could use the method QgsLineSymbol.setDataDefinedWidth()
layers = project.mapLayersByName("lines")

if layers:
    layer = layers[0]
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    scale = """coalesce(scale_exp("id", 0, 3, 1, 10, 0.57), 0)"""
    symbol.setDataDefinedWidth(QgsProperty.fromExpression(scale))
    layer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol))
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    print("Line width set based on 'id' attribute.")
else:
    print("Layer not found.")


Perfect, thanks!

@equa_peter, no problem :-)
